# Strange Java variable type with "cannot access" error, but in compilable code

Tags: types, ide, static-libraries, java

While coding, I have ran into a type that "behaves" neither like a primitive nor Object in my NetBeans IDE. The type is [IoBuffer from Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/buffer/IoBuffer.html) (but propabably the exact type has nothing to this question).

From my perspective:

- my project compiles well, despite that this type is used in lot places underneath
- my NetBeans don't recognize this type (`"cannot find symbol"` hint when i wrote `IoBuffer`)
- I can't create `IoBuffer` variable/instance (`compile error: "cannot find symbol"`)
- I can't invoke any method on that type, like `toString`.

Of course, this is a standard Java class, but it looks unusual from current perspective (Maven project of one of examples bundled with Red5 Media Server)

Simple invocation:

```
// videoData.getData() returns IoBuffer
videoData.getData().toString()
```

Causes hint & compile-time error:

`org/red5/demos/oflaDemo/StreamMultiplexer.java:[89,30] error: cannot access IoBuffer`

Same error if I write only `videoData.getData()` - hint in this case is `The type od getData() is erroneous`

What caused this situation?

Comment: Most likely the library is in your build path at compile time but NetBeans cannot find it for its code assistance. How is your project organised? Ant? Maven?

Comment: Note that using this code literally (`IoBuffer someVar`) causes **compile-time** error, not only hint. But lot of code connected uses this type underneath - `VideoData data;` compiles successfully.

Comment: Can you provide a self contained program that shows this behaviour, please?

Comment: @Vegard I think that could be hard, beacuse this problem is highly environment-specific not only code I think. I'm searching not for solution but what caused problem, se I can't reproduce it in small example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing netbeans cache? To clear cache: Shutdown Netbeans, rename %AppData%\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2\index, restart, wait for background scanning to complete and try again...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if my answer isn't specific enough. If you can provide some more code, that may help.

I believe the best way is to recreate that particular project and re-import the dependencies.
There's a number of people with seemingly similar errors:
http://forum.ragezone.com/f566/netbeans-compile-error-713536/
http://www.moparscape.org/smf/index.php?topic=645055.0

If that doesn't work, try:

- Changing the java version you are using. (http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/43174-constructor-cannot-find-symbol-compile-error.html)
- Clear your cache, delete all class files, recompile everything. (http://www.coderanch.com/t/402221/java/java/Compiler-Error-find-symbol)
- Close and Open the NetBeans project.
- Load the project in a different IDE, say eclipse.

Let me know if it helps.